# Angular2 Observable.forkJoin Unresolved function or method after upgrading

Tags: angular, observable

I upgraded my Angular2 project from beta.14 to **rc.4**.

Now I get

```
"Unresolved function or method"
```

on

```
Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(...)
           ^^^^^^^^
```

These are my imports:

```
import {Observable, Subscription} from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";
```

I added the second one after the upgrade but it does not help.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding

```
export * from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

in `my app/index.ts` file.
I hope this is the correct solution...